# How to make a search filter for data fetched from an API

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a search filter for some names of cryptocurrencies I mapped and fetched from an API. What I want to happen is that when the user types in the search bar, the crypto names that match their input, will show. The first issue I ran into is that I want to use the ".filter" method, but that data is not in an array so I can't do that. Is there another way I can make a search bar that shows the names of crypto currencies depending on the users input?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="title">Crytpo Currencies</h1></div>
  <div action=""><input placeholder= "Search for Crypto"type="text" name="searchbar" id="searchbar"></div>
  <ul class="subtitles">
      <li class="symbol-title">Symbol</li>
      <li class="name-title">Name</li>
      <li class="price-title">Price</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="dataaa"></div>
</body>

<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
}
body{
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0.8vw;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background-color: #1a1a1a ;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: linear-gradient( transparent, rgb(0, 255, 136));
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.title{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
#searchbar{
    margin-left: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    outline: none;
    border: white solid 1px;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
::placeholder{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.dataaa{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.pieceofdata{
    width: 100vw;
    border: 2px rgb(0, 255, 136) solid;
    display: flex;
    padding: 1em 0em;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.subtitles{
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0.8em;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 136) ;
}
.symbol{
    color: lime;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.name{
    justify-self: normal;
}
.price{

}
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
let elements = document.querySelector(".elements");
let dataaa = document.querySelector(".dataaa");
let searchbar = document.getElementById("searchbar");



function getdata() {
    fetch(
    'https://data.messari.io/api/v1/assets?fields=id,slug,symbol,metrics/market_data/price_usd'
  )
    .then((response) => {
      const data = response.json();
      return data;
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const html = data.data
        .map((pieceofdata) => {
          //VARIABLES OF DATA
          const name = pieceofdata.slug;
          const symbol = pieceofdata.symbol;
          const price = +pieceofdata.metrics.market_data.price_usd.toFixed(2);


          //HERE IS THE SEARCHBAR FUNCTION I AM HAVING ISSUES WITH ↓


          searchbar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
            let currentword = e.target.value
            if(name.includes(currentword)){
            dataaa.innerHTML = `<div class="pieceofdata"><h1 class= "symbol"> ${symbol}</h1><h1 class= "name"> ${name}</h1><h1 class="price"> $${price}</h1>
            </div>`;
            }
            else{
              dataaa.innerHTML = `<div class="pieceofdata"><h1 class= "symbol"> </h1><h1 class= "name"></h1> <h1 class="name">No Results Found</h1> <h1 class= "price"></h1>
              </div>`;
            }
          })
          
          return `<div class="pieceofdata"><h1 class= "symbol"> ${symbol}</h1><h1 class= "name"> ${name}</h1><h1 class= "price"> $${price}</h1>
            </div>`;
        })
      dataaa.innerHTML = html;

    });
}


getdata();
```

Comment: you need to show us the output from the API so that we can then help perhaps

Comment: @Mohamed It's a get request with no credentials, so you can just access the link in the fetch request to see the API output.

Comment: I think putting the searchbar code where you do doesn't make sense. It's better to assign the fetch result, and then call a function to map/render it.

Then, you can modify the data based on a search keyup (currently you have a search bar for searching the name of each individual result), and call the map/render function again.

Comment: @talfreds Thank you

Comment: @Matthewschlegel No worries, glad it helped. @ navnath has done exactly what I was suggesting, with very clean code.

Answer (score 0):

`Separate` `event listener` for a search field from API call. also, need to store API call data `(dataStore)`, so that you can access it later while searching. I have tried to separate all your code in much possible way. The filter will work according to `name`.

```js
let elements = document.querySelector(".elements");
let dataaa = document.querySelector(".dataaa");
let searchbar = document.getElementById("searchbar");
let dataStore = [];

getdata();

function getdata() {
    fetch(
    'https://data.messari.io/api/v1/assets?fields=id,slug,symbol,metrics/market_data/price_usd'
  )
    .then((response) => {
      const data = response.json();
      return data;
    })
    .then((data) => {
        dataStore = data.data;
        dataaa.innerHTML = getHTML(data.data);
    });
}

function getHTML(data){
    return data.map(({slug, symbol, metrics}) => generateHTML(slug, symbol, metrics)).join('');
}

function generateHTML(name, symbol, {market_data: { price_usd }}){
    return `<div class="pieceofdata"><h1 class= "symbol"> ${symbol}</h1><h1 class= "name"> ${name}</h1><h1 class= "price"> $${+price_usd.toFixed(2)}</h1>
        </div>`;
}

function noResultHTML(){
    return `<div class="pieceofdata"><h1 class= "symbol"> </h1><h1 class= "name"></h1> <h1 class="name">No Results Found</h1> <h1 class= "price"></h1>
      </div>`;
}

searchbar.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    const currentword = e.target.value;
    const filteredData= dataStore.filter(o => o.slug.includes(currentword));
    dataaa.innerHTML = filteredData.length ? getHTML(filteredData) : noResultHTML();
});
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
}
body{
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0.8vw;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background-color: #1a1a1a ;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: linear-gradient( transparent, rgb(0, 255, 136));
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.title{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
    margin-top: 0.5em;
}
#searchbar{
    margin-left: 80%;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    outline: none;
    border: white solid 1px;
    padding: 1em;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
::placeholder{
    color: white;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.dataaa{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.pieceofdata{
    width: 100vw;
    border: 2px rgb(0, 255, 136) solid;
    display: flex;
    padding: 1em 0em;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.subtitles{
    display: flex;
    width: 100vw;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 0.8em;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 136) ;
}
.symbol{
    color: lime;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.name{
    justify-self: normal;
}
.price{

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">-->
        <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="title">Crytpo Currencies</h1></div>
<div action=""><input placeholder= "Search for Crypto"type="text" name="searchbar" id="searchbar"></div>
        <ul class="subtitles">
        <li class="symbol-title">Symbol</li>
        <li class="name-title">Name</li>
        <li class="price-title">Price</li>
</ul>
        <div class="dataaa">
</body>

<!--<script src="main.js"></script>-->
</html>
```